# "New apps will save to:" option is disabled

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store-app

I had heard that it is possible to install Windows 10 Store apps to a different partition than the one on which Windows is installed, so I upgraded my computer to Windows 10, clean install. In the storage settings, I see "New apps will save to:", but it is grayed out. However, the respective options for documents, music, pictures and video are available. I have 2 external HDD on my computer and 1 SSD that has 120 GB of space.

I'm a bit disappointed that this didn't do want I wanted. How can I save Store apps to a different drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature "slipped" to the next release (October, I believe they were saying).

An official answer [quoting Bhavya Kashyap as of 2015-07-17](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_files/storage-sense-feature-new-apps-will-save-to-is/21ffcbe8-c813-40c6-a2ed-86a3ed9d70ec?auth=1):

> We have actually made the decision to postpone the apps on SD functionality to a later release. While I know this feature excited many of us, we didn't feel like it was ready for prime time. Our goal is to delight users with everything that we build, and we truly feel that that is what will happen once we have fully built our vision for this feature.

Comment: @prouser135 - FYI, this feature will be enabled in the "Fall Update" due in a few days.  See https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/7695/heres-whats-new-in-the-windows-10-fall-update