# How to force windows to install games from Store on D or other partitions?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

I don't have enough space on C drive so I'd like to install programs and games from Microsoft Store on the rest of my hard drive. Selecting other partitions is grayed out. How can I fix this? I would like also to know if my computer has a virus that causes weird things like that or is it just a bug in the version windows? Thank you,

[image]

BTW, I also tried to move already installed games from C to D but it's also not available.

Comment: It is not a bug - I just tried it. Are you using a Drive Letter that Windows Explorer can see?

Comment: I am able to choose a drive.  While I agree it’s not a bug (something else is going on) it certainly should be possible

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run: dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  . Follow this with SFC /SCANNOW  .   Restart and test

Comment: Apparently this feature was disabled in earlier Windows versions and was only available for non PC editions, it was apparently changed in the fall creators update https://superuser.com/questions/950561/new-apps-will-save-to-option-is-disabled Are you maybe using a really outdated version of Windows 10?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 V1909 18363.592.  I temporarily relocated a folder and then put it back to the original location. The Microsoft stuff has enough room on C: so I did not move that

Comment: @John I tried the code but I got this reply:

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10240.16384


Error: 11

You cannot service a running 64-bit operating system with a 32-bit version of DISM.
Please use the version of DISM that corresponds to your computer's architecture.

Comment: Yes, I have an old version of windows 10. It seems that I have to install a newer one :) Thanks for the all the comments.

Comment: The error indicates something more seriously wrong. At this point, you might consider a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @John Okay, thank you so much for your assistance. Really appreciated :)

Comment: What format (FAT32, exFAT, NTFS) are the "other partitions"? I think you may need them formatted NTFS.

Comment: @Mokubai They are already NTFS. The previous comments tell that it's an issue with the version of windows so I'm going to try to update it :)